# Updating the principal in all of the user's sessions in Spring Webflux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-session

Disclaimer: I'm new to Spring.

Hey,
I want the principal object to always be updated for all sessions, so that I can avoid extra database queries when I want to use the currently logged in user. I'm thinking of achieving this by updating all of a user's sessions when the user is saved to the database.

I did some research, and I found this GitHub issue (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/398), which brought me to here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-findbyusername.html.

However, this appears to be blocking, and looking at the other session repositories, they do not seem to have an equivalent of "findByPrincipalName", which allows me to get all of the user's sessions. Am I missing something? Is there another way to approach updating the principal of all of a user's sessions?

By the way, I am using redis for session storage.

Thanks!